# Problem about differential of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Please can you tell how to solve this problem clearly? Please solve this explanatorily. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Write down the definition of a differential of a map, and use the fact that $L$ is linear to show that $dL = L$.

Comment: @user66345 please can you show the solution explanatorily  below?

Comment: @user66345 please help me! I want to learn how to solve.

Comment: What is the definition of the differential of a map?

Comment: Let $F:N→M$ bea$C^{∞}$ map between two manifolds.Ateachpoint $p∈N$,themap $F$ induces a linear map of tangent spaces, called its differential at p,
$F_{∗} : T_{p}N → T_{F(p)}M$ @user66345

Comment: Ok, but it's just the matrix of partial derivatives.

Comment: So? What do you mean? I didnt understand:( @user66345

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say that $F: N^n \to M^m$ is a smooth function, mapping
$$
p = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_m \end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} F_1(p) \\ \vdots \\ F_m(p) \end{bmatrix}
= F(p).
$$

Then, the differential is linear map $F_{*,p}: T_p(N) \to T_{F(p)}(M)$ between the tangent spaces.  Choosing the basis $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \}$ for $T_p(N)$ and the basis $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial y_m} \}$ for $T_{F(p)}(M)$, we can represent the differential by the $(m \times n)$-matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_n} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1(x)}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_1(x)}{\partial x_n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial F_m(x)}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_m(x)}{\partial x_n} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In the special case that $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map, we can write $L(x) = Ax$, where $A$ is an $(m \times n)$-matrix.

What do the partial derivatives look like?  Put $A = [a_{ij}]$, so for any $1 \le i \le m$,
$$
y_i = F_i(x) = a_{i1}x_1 + \cdots + a_{in}x_n,
$$
and for any $1 \le i \le m$, $1 \le j \le n$,
$$
\frac{\partial F_i(x)}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\big( a_{i1}x_1 + \cdots + a_{in}x_n \big) = a_{ij}.
$$

Thus, the matrix of partial derivatives, representing the differential of $L$ in coordinates, is nothing other than the matrix of $L$ itself, once we make the identification $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Really thank you for help:) Now I Try to understand this:) @SammyBlack

Comment: Upon rereading this, I notice a slight abuse of notation.  I seem to be identifying the point $p \in N$ with its coordinates $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  (This is standard practice when doing computations in coordinates).  It's nice to pay attention to these details when you're first learning about manifolds, though.

Comment: Okay, I am careful of what you said.

Comment: By the way, you wrote extremely in depth. All are so clear. I am udertanding well. :)