# Numerical derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus

I have an expression

$$ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{s}
$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $\mathbf{s}$ is a $n \times 1$ vector. The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is itself a function of $\mathbf{s}$

$$ \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{s})$$

I am wondering how I firstly, compute the derivative of this expression and secondly, numerically estimate the derivative at some vector $\mathbf{s}_0$. My attempt has been to apply the product rule in some way

$$ \frac{d}{d\mathbf{s}} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{s})\mathbf{s} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{s}) + \mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{s})\mathbf{s} $$

noting that $\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{s})$ is a $(n \times n) \times n$ matrix so that the derivative above is a matrix of dimension $n \times n$ if we consider the term $\mathbf{f}'(\mathbf{s})\mathbf{s}$ as an $n \times n$ matrix expressed with its columns placed below each other.

I am not completely sure whether my approach is correct and additionally, how to proceed from here in terms of numerically evaluating this derivative at a particular vector. I plan to use Matlab to compute a numerical derivative.

Any assistance or input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem about differential of a linear map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357519)

Comment: If your goal is numerical to begin with, don’t bother with the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, $f'(s)$ is not a matrix, it is a third-order tensor with dimensions $(n\times n\times n)$

Such tensors are awkward to work with. The easiest way to proceed is to [vectorize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the matrix
$$\eqalign{
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
a &= \vecc{A} \:&\in\:&\bbR{n^2} \\\
J &= \grad{a}{s} \:&\in\:&\bbR{n^2\times n}\quad&\{ {\,\rm Jacobian\,} \} \\
da &= J\:ds &&&\{ {\,\rm differential\,} \} \\
}$$
Now the gradient calculation will not involve any tensors
$$\eqalign{
y &= As \\
dy &= A\:ds + I_ndA\:s \\
 &= A\:ds + \LR{s^T\otimes I_n}da \\
 &= \LR{A + \LR{s^T\otimes I_n}J}ds \\
\grad{y}{s} &= A + \LR{s^T\otimes I_n}J \\
}$$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the matrix product notation in Tom M. Apostol's Calculus book. In this notation the matrices
$$
s=
\left\lgroup
\begin{array}{c}
s_{11}\\ s_{21}\\ \vdots \\ s_{i 1} \\ \vdots \\ s_{n1} 
\end{array}\right\rgroup
\qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad 
f(s)=
\left\lgroup
\begin{array}{cc c c c c}
f_{11}(s) & f_{12}(s) & \ldots &   f_{1j}(s)  & \ldots & f_{1n}(s)
\\
f_{21}(s) & f_{22}(s) & \ldots &   f_{2j}(s)  & \ldots & f_{1n}(s)
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots &   \vdots  & \ldots & \vdots
\\
f_{i1}(s) & f_{i2}(s) & \ldots &   f_{ij}(s)  & \ldots & f_{in}(s)
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots &   \vdots  & \ldots & \vdots
\\
f_{n1}(s)    & f_{n2}(s)   & \ldots &   f_{nj}(s)  & \ldots & f_{nn}(s)
\end{array}\right\rgroup
$$
are denoted most economically by
$$
s=( s_{i1})_{i=1}^{\;\;\,n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}
\qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  
f(s)= (f_{ij})_{i=1,\;j=1}^{\;\;\,n ,\;\;\; n} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}
$$
Also in this notation the product $f(s)\cdot s \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ is
$$
f(s)\cdot s = \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_{ik}(s)\cdot s_{k 1}  \Big)_{i=1}^{\;\;\, n}
$$
Thus it is clear to see that the $i$-th coordinate function of $s\mapsto f(s)\cdot s$ is the function
$$
\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}\ni s \mapsto \Big( f(s)\cdot s \Big)_{i1} =\sum_{k=1}^{n} f_{ik}(s)\cdot s_{k 1}\in \mathbb{R}
$$
whose derivative at the $\ell$-th coordinate of the variable $s$ is
\begin{align}
D_{\ell}\Big( f(s)\cdot s \Big)_{i1}
= & 
D_{\ell}\Big( \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_{ik}(s)\cdot s_{k 1} \Big)
\\
= & 
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}D_{\ell}f_{ik}(s)\Big)\cdot s_{k 1} + f_{i\ell}(s)
\end{align}
Thus the gradient of $\Big( f(s)\cdot s \Big)_{i1}$ is the line vector
$$
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}D_{\ell}f_{ik}(s)\cdot s_{k 1} + f_{i\ell}(s)\Big)_{\ell =1 }^{\;\;\;\,n} \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}
$$
Therefore the gradient of
$$
\mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} \ni s \longmapsto \Big\lgroup\big( f(s)\cdot s \big)_{i1}\Big\rgroup_{i=1}^{\;\;\, n}=
\left\lgroup
\begin{array}{c}
\big( f(s)\cdot s \big)_{11}\\  \vdots \\ \big( f(s)\cdot s \big)_{i1} \\ \vdots \\ \big( f(s)\cdot s \big)_{n1}
\end{array}\right\rgroup
$$
is the matrix
$$
\Big\lgroup\sum_{k=1}^{n}D_{\ell}f_{ik}(s)\cdot s_{k 1}\Big\rgroup_{i=1\,\ell=1}^{\;\;\, n \;\;\, n} + \Big\lgroup f_{i\ell}(s)\Big\rgroup_{i=1\,\ell=1}^{\;\;\, n \;\;\, n}
$$